# Javascript - How to replace white spaces which are not in HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, replace, tags, space

The following codes doesn't work and the result is broken because there are white spaces in a HTML tag.

HTML:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum <a id="demo" href="demo" rel="demo">dolor sit amet</a>, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, '<span class="space"> </span>');
```

How to replace replace white spaces which are not in HTML tags?

Comment: you need to recursively iterate over the text nodes, splitting the text node values by the space chartacter, and then replacing that by spans and new text nodes.

Comment: Question: what do you need to replace spaces with spans for?

Comment: @chris, could you give me an example?

Comment: @Truth, spans are just for illustration. I just need a way to find those \s and do something with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a better idea to actually use the DOM functions rather than some unreliable string manipulation using a regexp. [`splitText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Text.splitText) is a function of text nodes that allows you to split text nodes. It comes in handy here as it allows you to split at spaces and insert a `<span>` element between them. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m5Qe8/2/.

```
var div = document.querySelector("div");

// generates a space span element
function space() {
    var elem = document.createElement("span");
    elem.className = "space";
    elem.textContent = " ";
    return elem;
}

// this function iterates over all nodes, replacing spaces
// with space span elements
function replace(elem) {
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var node = elem.childNodes[i];
        if(node.nodeType === 1) {
            // it's an element node, so call recursively
            // (e.g. the <a> element)
            replace(node);
        } else {
            var current = node;
            var pos;
            while(~(pos = current.nodeValue.indexOf(" "))) {
                var next = current.splitText(pos + 1);
                current.nodeValue = current.nodeValue.slice(0, -1);
                current.parentNode.insertBefore(space(), next);
                current = next;
                i += 2;  // childNodes is a live array-like object
                         // so it's necessary to advance the loop
                         // cursor as well
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And when texts are split by "line break + tab" instead of white spaces, this seem not work.

Comment: @Ian Y: In IE9 there seems to be a problem that `splitText` does not set `parentNode` corretly for the two new text nodes. I'm not sure how to solve that (IE's debugging tools are horrible). As for line breaks, how exactly are you splitting? Note that you'd have to change the `+ 1` and `-1` appropriately as well in case you're splitting on successive characters.

Comment: With regard to the line breaks and tabs, although that doesn't occur everywhere, contents of paragraphs in HTML source may not always being tidy due to many reasons so there can be line breaks or even tabs in the middle of paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works. Would you like to put this code on your personal website so people can mention its author when they use it?

Comment: @Ian Y.: I don't have a personal website and I don't need credits :). You could just link to this answer if you'd like to.

Comment: @Ian Y.: I found a bug where it actually replaced `n` spaces with `n` space spans. Here's a patched version: http://jsfiddle.net/m5Qe8/5/.

Comment: Thank you! :) Please patch it whenever you notice a new bug.

Comment: There seem to be one more: tabs/breaks/spaces at the very beginning and the very end are being replaced, too, but they actually don't need to be replaced.

Comment: @Ian Y.: That one is tricky because even if a text node contains spaces at the beginning/end, they may be not be ignorable. For example, in `" Lorem ipsum <a ...>"` the first space of the text node `" Lorem ipsum "` should *not* get a space span, but the last one should. I'm not sure if there's a trivial fix for that. On jsFiddle though, superfluous space spans are not colored, so apparently they're automatically hidden.

Answer (score 0):

First split the string at every occurrence of `>` or `<`. Then fit together all parts to a string again by replacing spaces only at the even parts:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var parts = div.innerHTML.split(/[<>]/g);
var newHtml = '';
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    newHtml += (i % 2 == 0 ? parts[i].replace(/\s/g, '<span class="space"> </span>') : '<' + parts[i] + '>');
}
div.innerHTML = newHtml;
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kWKpX/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

Ok, the result of th IE split can be different then the result of split of all other browsers. With following workaround it should work:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var sHtml = ' ' + div.innerHTML;
var sHtml = sHtml.replace(/\>\</g, '> <');
var parts = sHtml.split(/[<>]/g);
var newHtml = '';
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        parts[i] = parts[i].substr(1);
    }
    newHtml += (
        i % 2 == 0 ? 
        parts[i].replace(/\s/g, '<span class="space"> </span>') : 
        '<' + parts[i] + '>'
    );
}
div.innerHTML = newHtml;
```

Also see [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/SCeXJ/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

Ok, I have completly changed my script. It's tested with IE8 and current firefox.

```
function parseNodes(oElement) {
    for (var i = oElement.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var oCurrent = oElement.childNodes[i];
        if (oCurrent.nodeType != 3) {
            parseNodes(oElement.childNodes[i]);
        } else {
            var sText = (typeof oCurrent.nodeValue != 'undefined' ? oCurrent.nodeValue : oCurrent.textContent);
            var aParts = sText.split(/\s+/g);
            for (var j = 0; j < aParts.length; j++) {
                var oNew = document.createTextNode(aParts[j]);
                oElement.insertBefore(oNew, oCurrent);
                if (j < aParts.length - 1) {
                    var oSpan = document.createElement('span');
                    oSpan.className = 'space';
                    oElement.insertBefore(oSpan, oCurrent);
                    var oNew = document.createTextNode(' ');
                    oSpan.appendChild(oNew);
                }
            }
            oElement.removeChild(oCurrent);
        }
    }
}

var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
parseNodes(div);
```

Also see [the new example](http://jsfiddle.net/QjZsZ/).

Comment: Thank you. However, IE7/8 have problems with the following HTML: <div><strong>Bla</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

Comment: And with this one, too: <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <strong>BlaBla<em>Bla</em></strong> adipiscing elit.</div>

Comment: The `<center>` cannot hold. It is too late.

Comment: Thank you. It is close. The following code will get an additional space: <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <strong>BlaBla<em>Bla</em></strong>BlaBlaBa adipiscing elit.</div>

Comment: Sorry, but in IE8, some white spaces are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with the text content of the container, and ignore the markup.

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
if(div.textContent){
    div.textContent=div.textContent.replace(/(\s+)/g,'<span class="space"> </span>';
}
else if(div.innerText){
    div.innerText=div.innerText.replace(/(\s+)/g,'<span class="space"> </span>';
}
```

Comment: are you _sure_ you can HTML into an `innertText` attribute?

Comment: Thank you. But the result shows <span class="space"> </span> directly on webpage.